# How do I switch between walking and running?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

My character had always run since I began to play. Today I probably hit a key/parameter and he's slowly walking.

How do I switch between walking and running?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Press <kbd>/</kbd> on the numeric keypad and you'll toggle between run/walk.

Otherwise, open Key Bindings, Movement Keys and set your "Toggle Run/Walk" to an unbound key.